# How to fetch data from mysql within given condition using spring MVC

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa, repository

Here is my service implementation method:

```js
@Override
    public List<Question> getQuestion(Long questionId, int page, int records, String organizationId) throws InvalidIdException {

        Organization existingOrganization=organizationRepository.findOne(siteUtil.getDecryptedId(organizationId));
        Pageable pageInfo=new PageRequest(page-1,records);
        Page<com.oAssessment.entity.Question> existingQuestions=questionRepository.findAllByOrganizationAndDeleted
                (existingOrganization,false,pageInfo);
        List<Question> existingQuestion = new ArrayList<>();
        if(existingQuestions.hasContent()) {
            Iterator<com.oAssessment.entity.Question> existingQustionIterator = existingQuestions.iterator();
            while(existingQustionIterator.hasNext()) {
                com.oAssessment.entity.Question newQuestion = existingQustionIterator.next();
                Question question = new Question();
                if(newQuestion.getPkQuestionId()!=null) {
                    question.setSerialNo(newQuestion.getSerialNo());
                    question.setQuestionText(newQuestion.getText());
                    question.setDifLevel(newQuestion.getDifLevel());
                    question.setTypeOfquestion(newQuestion.getTypeOfQuestion());
                    existingQuestion.add(question);
                }
            }
        }
        return existingQuestion;
    }
```

And the jpa repository be like

```js
@Repository
public interface QuestionRepository extends JpaRepository<Question, Long> {

    Page<Question> findAllByOrganizationAndDeleted(Organization existingOrganization, boolean b, Pageable pageInfo);

}
```

By this, all the data coming from database. But I just want to put some condition to filter out data. Like I want to fetch some of the questions from database basis on a given topic, no of question, question difficulty level like this. But the data should come randomly from database. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter out your data in `Spring Data`, you can use `Specifications`, `Query by Example` and `Querydsl Extension` which i recommend to go for `Specifications` because i think it's more powerful. You can take a look at [`Spring Data JPA - Reference Documentation`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) for more information.

And for sorting your data randomly, i don't think you can do that in `Spring Data` because AFAIK not all the databases have that feature. How about you first find the total count of your filtered questions and then query for a random page of it?